# Grouping Algorithm with Requirements

Tags: algorithm, grouping

So I am working on writing an algorithm that when given a group of people from different places, it will organize them into groups of three based off a few parameters:

1. No two people in a group are from the same place
2. No two people in a group have met before
3. Everyone in the group is available to meet on the same day
4. Not more than one person is below the age of 18

I have in my data structures a variable for all the required prereqs above. I was wondering if there was a good way to go about solving this problem? Currently I am using a variation of the Gale-Shapely Algorithm (solution to Stable Marriage Problem). This solution works relatively well, but more often that not, it requires me to go in and make some minor tweaks to the final groups.

Any one have any ideas/suggestions?

I appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [graph partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition) problem, and as such it's almost certainly NP-Hard (when you've only got one constraint then the problem can be solved in polynomial time - this is similar to the stable marriage problem - but when you've got multiple constraints then the complexity shoots way up).  A good way to solve these problems is to apply a heuristic (which you're doing with the Gale-Shapely algorithm), and to then resolve any conflicts with a local backtracking search (which it sounds like you're currently doing by hand).  My suggestion is to keep your current heuristic if it seems to be working well for you, and to add an automated local backtracking algorithm to resolve any conflicts that arise from the heuristic (e.g. if you've got a single group that has two people who are under 18, then swap one of these people with somebody who is over 18 and who doesn't violate the other three constraints; if this isn't possible, then choose somebody who is over 18 who violates the fewest constraints, and then swap out somebody else from the group in order to satisfy the now violated constraint; after N failed iterations the algorithm throws up its hand and asks for human intervention)

Comment: Awesome answer. I assumed it was some kind of NP type problem, wanted to confirm through someone else. I really appreciate the help!